# Should a math major who wants to get into a PhD program in AI take CS classes that are unrelated to AI research?

Tags: education

I am a 2nd year math major who wants to do a PhD in AI. I already have a little background in programming and CS. I have some experience in game design, app development and computer security. I wouldn't call myself an expert, but I am comfortable with C, C++, Python, Javascript C#, Java and Assembly and have written and sold a couple of commercial software to businesses before. I am also somewhat familiar with amortized analysis, data structures, algorithms and proofs of correctness. My question is, do I still have to take introductory classes in order to prove to graduate schools that I know programming or is it okay if I only take classes related to AI research like algorithms, machine learning and introduction to artifical intelligence? Also, do I need to take "engineering" type classes like digital design, operating systems, databases etc. that are normally required from computer science students but not related to AI research?
Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer these questions.

Comment: If you want to know what you **need** to take, it would probably be better to ask over at academia.stackexchange or to just research your target PHD programs.

Comment: Everything in IT, Software, and Mathematics is about details. My recommendation is to get your basics undercontrol whether you do that in course work or by using katas. Secondly do not just rely on the course work. There is a library filled with books, and with access to leading research journals. Spend you spare time there soaking up knowledge. Third AI research is a very cross-functional field, pay attention to the biology, pschology, phylosphy, and any other field which studies life/intellegence in some way.